# ObservableCollection w/ .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, compiler-errors, observablecollection

I have a project that was being compiled in .net 3.5, when I converted it to .net 4.0 I receive a compile error saying:

"The base class or interface of 'MyApplication.ClassName' could not be resolved or in invalid."

This class implements ObservableCollection but other than that there is nothing special about it. Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What is your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` class was defined in `WindowsBase.dll` in v3.0 and was moved to `System.dll` in v4.0. Maybe you should check your project's references.